# Which PHP Web framework for Firebird?

Tags: php, frameworks, firebird

Is there any PHP web framework that works cleanly with the **Firebird** database?

By "cleanly", I mean out-of-the-box, no hacks/customization/self-made drivers.

So far, I've checked out frameworks like **CodeIgniter** & **CakePHP**, but their support for Firebird is vague or little at most.

Answer (score 3):

The Zend Framework has a [Firebird / Interbase DB adapter in incubation](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Db+Firebird-Interbase+support), so almost clean out of the box (and I've used it, and it worked like a charm for me). Mind you, there's an [experimental PDO adapter for Firebird](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php) as well, and with that in place, any framework that use PDO is going to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework is working on Firebird-Interbase support. [You can check out the progress here.](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Db+Firebird-Interbase+support)

Answer (score 1):

cake php supports it out of the box, http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2008/08/cakephp-tutorial-for-ubuntu-firebird.html

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework has support for Firebird and Interbase in the "Extras", you must download the "Full Package" instead of "Minimum Package".

I developed this Adapter, if you need some help, please subscribe and post in fw-db@lists.zend.com.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding a framework that supports FireBird why not use a framework you are familiar with and use ADOBD lib for accessing a plethora of RBDMSs out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

[With Delphi for Php](http://forums.delphi-php.net/tutorials/3656-how-connect-firebird-db-server-delphi-php.html)

or

[TurboForPhp](http://www.turbophp.com/) (OpenSource)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [YII](http://www.yiiframework.com/) framework out there

it's not completely out-of-the-box, but quite straight forward

[https://github.com/robregonm/YiiFirebird - for Yii 1](https://github.com/robregonm/YiiFirebird)

[https://github.com/edgardmessias/yii2-firebird - for Yii 2](https://github.com/edgardmessias/yii2-firebird)